# How to make windows into a wall?

Tags: modeling

I want to know how to cut a cube and delete some parts of it!

[This is the original cube!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6g9P.jpg)
[image]

[This is how I want to cut it... I made this with paint!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBUTo.jpg)

[image]

Comment: There is a good tutorial on [cutting holes into objects](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA), which is a generalization of your question and might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 11):

Select the face where you want the window,

[image]

press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude and move the newly created wall in the direction you want the extrusion.

[image]

You can delete then the selected face.

[image]

**EDIT** Another quick way to make a window is using the inset tool.

Select the face on which you want to make the window, press <kbd>I</kbd> and drag the mouse. That will create a new face of similar proportions connected to the edges of the original wall. Then extrude by pressing <kbd>E</kbd> and dragging the mouse to create the depth for the window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## How to create a door or window opening in a wall in blender

These are the steps I use to create window and door openings in walls in blender:

[image: Image that describes the steps to create a door or window opening in a wall in blender]